# PostgreSQL - do we need to DROP the database and recreate it if we want to RESTORE it?

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, postgresql-11, pg-restore

I worked with many different databases (SQL Server, Oracle, IBM db2) and for all of them if we have a backup it is just enough to execute RESTORE command in order to restore the data.

I am beginner in PostgreSQL.

As I see in documentation and on this question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289888/restore-postgres-database-dump
for succesfull restoration of the database we need to:

```
* DROP database
* CREATE database
* execute psql dbname < dumpfile
```

I am really confused (based on the behavior from all other databases ) that we need to drop and recreate database if we want to restore? It's hard for me to believe that Postgres really is implemented in that way.

Answer (score 4):

If you run `pg_dump` with the `--clean` option then the generated SQL dump would contain `drop` statements for all dumped objects (note that when using the custom format and `pg_restore` you don't need to decide on this when dumping, but when restoring).

However if the target database contains tables (or other objects) that were not contained in the source, those would **not** be dropped.

Using `pg_dump --clean` (or `pg_restore --clean`) is pretty much the same behaviour as with Oracle's  `impdp` using the `TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE`. That too wouldn't drop (replace) tables that were not part of the source.

To avoid having tables in the target that were not contained in the source, people very often simply drop the entire database before importing the dump. But this is (when using the `--clean` option) not really required.

Comment: Hi. I used pg_dump tinker > tinker.bak command for backup and I found psql dbname < dumpfile for restore. Should I use pg_restore instead?

Comment: If you created the dump using a plain text dump (which is the default when using `pg_dump`)  then you can only restore it using `psql`. If you want to use `pg_restore` you have to create a "custom format" dump, using `pg_dump --format=c ...`

Comment: sorry I am not sure what is this custom format dump? can you give me an example? thanks

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html#APP-PGRESTORE-EXAMPLES

Comment: I  still cannot understand based on the documentation what is custom format? Can you please explain? " Specify format of the archive. It is not necessary to specify the format, since pg_restore will determine the format automatically. If specified, it can be one of the following: c
custom
    The archive is in the custom format of pg_dump."

Comment: I think that you did not answer my question. My question was not -if there are tables which exist on destination but not and on the source. I see that you are mentioning that couple of times. My question is it required to executed drop statement - either explicitly (using the drop command) or implicitly (using the --clean command). We always must in someway DROP the tables? Consider the use case when they both have the same data structure (same columns and tables) because this is the same server! I just want to restore it if something goes wrong.